# I have a single processor with 4 physical cores, and each core has 2 threads. But why runtime.NumCPU() returns 4 rather than 8?

Tags: go

I have a single processor with 4 physical cores, and each core has 2 threads. But why runtime.NumCPU() returns 4 rather than 8?

My CPU details:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               78
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
```

When I run the following code:
`fmt.Println(runtime.NumCPU())`

it outputs 4.

Each hardware thread will be presented to the Go program as a virtual core, so the output should be 8, isn't it?

But why the output is 4?

Comment: You have 4 CPUs and 4 is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU has two physical cores, not 4. From Intel's product info sheet for the [Intel® Core™ i5-6200U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88193/intel-core-i5-6200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz.html):

> # of Cores 2
>
> # of Threads 4

So the `NumCPU()` value of 4 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU details: `CPU(s): 4`. That's pretty self explanatory.

But to add the math:

```
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1


Num CPU(s) = Num Socket(s) * Core(s) per socket * Thread(s) per core
           = 1             * 2                  * 2
           = 4
```

You have 4 logical CPUs, and [`runtime.NumCPU()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU) *returns the number of logical CPUs usable by the current process.* All 4 logical CPUs are available to your app (by default), so that's why `runtime.NumCPU()` reports 4.